# "DB Navigator" vs. "Data Sources and Drivers" in IDEA

Tags: oracle, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEa 2017.1.1

There seem to be two different ways of being connected to a database in IDEa. I am connecting to an Oracle db.

There is a DB browser, which is much less functional. I need to provide a connection to it. Then it looks a bit like this. This is the interaface I'd rather avoid. 
[image]

Then there is "Database" which has a different interface, but works very similarly and has a better user experience. [image]

They provide different functionality when editing a file. When I create a new scratch file, the better feature is used - code completion works with the content from the Data sources from the Data Source and Driver interface. However, when I edit an SQL project file, I have to use the other interface - I have to select a connection from the DB Navigator.

A colleague of mine uses IDEa too, but for him, however, even SQL files use the Data Sources and Drivers interface and the content of those connections as source for auto completion. Why this difference? Why two interfaces that do the same? How can I set IDEa to use the Data Sources and Drivers for my project SQL files?

Comment: DB Navigator is a third-party plugin. "Data Sources" is built-in IDEA functionality. You should uninstall the plugin.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try!

Comment: @yole This resolved my issue. Please post it as an answer, so you can receive reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB Navigator is a third-party plugin that duplicates and overrides some of IntelliJ IDEA's database access features. Uninstalling the plugin should get you the same UI as what your colleague has.